# Get and set focus position in SWT browser

Tags: java, browser, swt

I want to get and set the position within a SWT browser but I don't know how.

First, I created a browser control:

```
Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
```

Then I launched a HTML document:

```
File file = new File("C:\\test\\index.html");
browser.setUrl(file.toURI().toString());
```

That works perfect so far.
Now I scroll down the page to find an interesting text passage and click a menu item to create a kind of bookmark.
My question is: How can I get the current focus position (x,y) to remember the point in the text and how can I reset the position later to "apply" a specific bookmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interact with the browser content through `Browser#evaluate()` and `Browser#execute()`.
Both methods allow to execute Javascript in the context of the browsers document.

To send Javascript code that queries the current position, use something like:

```
Object position = browser.evaluate( "window.getCurrentPosition();" );
```

The type of the return value depends on the code that is evaluated. Debug through the code to see what the actual return type is.

If you aren't interested in the return value, use `execute`. For example to set the current position you would use:

```
browser.evaluate( "window.setCurrentPosition( x, y );" );
```

Please note that the Javascript is pseudo-code and doesn't actually return the current position.

If you run into `SWTException`s, it is likely that the document isn't fully loaded yet and you need to delay the execution of the Javascript code until it is fully loaded as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7802717/2986905